# Finding the number of reduced fractions

Tags: python

I've been working on this problem for the last two days. I feel like I'm dangerously close; but something is not quite clicking. Would love a fresh pair of eyes to run through this- open to any suggestions.

The task is to find the number of fully reduced fractions for any denominator.
Brute force works to a certain extent, but I need to be able to find results for upwards of 10^10. The full challenge is here:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/number-of-proper-fractions-with-denominator-d/train/python

Where my code sits currently:

```
def proper_fractions(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0

    numbers = set(range(int(n * 0.5), 1, -1))
    primes = []
    while numbers:
        p = numbers.pop()
        primes.append(p)
        numbers.difference_update(set(range(p * 2, n + 1, p)))

    counter = n

    for num in primes:
        if n % num == 0:
            counter = counter - (n//num)
            n = n//num
            if num >= (n ** 0.5):
                break

    if n == 1:
        return counter
    elif n > 1:
        return counter - (counter // n)
```

Comment: Why do you think you're dangerously close?  What test cases have you tried, and which ones failed?

Comment: All the test cases hold true - n = 1, 2, 4, 8, 15. 

However n = 25 returns 16, when it should return 20.

Answer (score 5):

The number you need to compute is called [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), the numbers of `n`'s coprimes between `1` and `n`.

If the prime decomposotion of `n` is:

[image: prime decomposotion of n],

its Euler's totient function is:

[image: Euler's totient function formula]

The algorithm to compute it in pseudocode:

> - `φ = 1`
> - `m = n`
> - For every prime number `p` less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`:
>
>   - If `m` divides `p`:
>
>     - Multiply `φ` by `p-1`
>     - Divide `m` by `p-1`
>   - While `m` divides `p`:
>
>     - Multiply `φ` by `p`
>     - Divide `m` by `p`
> - If `m > 1`:
>
>   - *// Note that at this point `m` must be a prime factor of `n` greater than `sqrt(n)`*
>   - Multiply `φ` by `m-1`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to is for the denominator supplied check to see if the gcd is 1 and if it is output to a list and then return the length of that list.

```
def proper_fractions(n):
    def gcd(x,y):
        while y:
            (x, y) = (y, x % y)
        return x
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        count = 0
        for num in range(1,n):
            denom = gcd(n,num)
            if denom == 1:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, I appreciate the quick response! My first attempt was along those lines; (yours runs far quicker..) but I ran into memory errors when iterating through ranges upwards of a billion characters. Any recommendations for finding the result without iterating  through an entire range?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Euler's totient function, as the user Anton has already stated. Here is one way to solve the problem. I've put some comments in the code.

```
def proper_fractions(n):
  distinct_prime_factors = set()   # use set to avoid duplicates
  totient_function = n
  if n == 1:
    totient_function = 0
  else:
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
      if n % i == 0:
        distinct_prime_factors.add(i)
        n = n/i
      else:
        i += 1
    if n > 1:
      distinct_prime_factors.add(n)   # picks up prime factors > sqrt(n)
    if len(distinct_prime_factors) == 0:   # empty set means denominator is prime
      totient_function = n - 1
    else:
      for p in distinct_prime_factors:
        totient_function = (totient_function*(p - 1))/p
  return totient_function
```

Euler's totient function uses the distinct prime factors. This is why it is better to use a set instead of a list, since sets don't allow for repeated elements.

Furthermore, after the while loop, it is important to add n to the set of prime factors if n is greater than 1. This is because the while loop terminates as soon as the prime factors are greater than the square root of n. For example, consider the number 77. The while loop will pick up 7, since 7*7 = 49, which is less than 77. However, it will not pick up 11, since 11*11 = 121, which is greater than 77.